# MovieTexture alternative for Samsung Gear VR in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I can use a MovieTexture to play a video file in the Unity Editor, but trying to build to Android causes a compiler error.  A little digging shows that Android does not support MovieTexture, only full screen video playout.

But I've seen apps on the Samsung Gear VR that play a video non-full screen with various 3d assets around (such as a virtual theater).  Clearly non-full screen video is possible.

How is this accomplished? I've seen references to 360 video tutorials, but nothing like what I want to figure out.  Do I HAVE to use the native sdk for this functionality?  If so, are there any good tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EasyMovieTexture is an excellent option, i've tried a bunch of other ones and they don't hold a candle to it.

You can find it in the assets store, it's about 40 dollars if i remember correctly.

Comment: And it works with the Samsung Gear VR? Not just non-mobile stuff?

Comment: absolutely, i developed a few projects with it, you can play either local files or do HLS streaming, i played resolutions up to 4k on the gearvr, it does not work on desktop, only ios tvos and android

Answer (score 0):

A year later I have also tried MPMP (MultiPlatformMediaPlayer) (in addition to EasyMovieTexture). Neither exactly fit my needs, but both are solid options.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Movie texture is best option available to showcase your video in different format even in 360 form on 2d plane also you can use realtime streaming by using this package.
https://github.com/maazirfan/Easy-Movie-Texture-for-Unity 
you can have this package from above link 
i used this in gear VR using samsung s6 so it work fine, but only mp4 format runs in it.